# Change label color on input focus in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

Given this code, I can not change the color of my label, no matter what I use - `focus, :checked, hover` etc.

I have read multiple threads here on stackoverflow, but somehow I can't seem to cope with this issue.

I know that in order to use the `+` selector, the label must be after the input.

Is it bad for SEO if I put the label after the input..?

Is this possible with pure CSS(SCSS) or do I need jQuery?

```css
.widg-input {
  .input {
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: .1rem solid green;
    }
    &:checked {
      +.input-label {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="widg-input">
  <label for="input1" class="input-label">firstname</label>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="input1" placeholder="John">
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a label after an input is not bad for SEO. The `for` attribute associates the two elements. Bots will respect that.

You can put the label after the input, then use `flex` and `order` to re-arrange them visually.

Your SCSS would look like

```
.widg-input {
  display: flex;
  .input-label {
    order: -1;
  }
  .input {
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: .1rem solid green;
      + .input-label {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the rendered result

```css
.widg-input {
  display: flex;
}
.widg-input .input-label {
  order: -1;
}
.widg-input .input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .1rem solid green;
}
.widg-input .input:focus + .input-label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="widg-input">
  <input type="text" class="input" name="input1" placeholder="John">
  <label for="input1" class="input-label">firstname</label>
</section>
```

Comment: A much needed SEO/Flex greenlight. Thanks!